# URL having a & getting encoded in a ASP.NET repeater control

Tags: asp.net, character-encoding

I have a URL which is in a ASP.NET repeater control:

```
http://www.someurl.com/test.aspx?abc=t&bd=1
```

This gets encoded to `&amp;` when it gets rendered to the browser.

We have tried decoding it using server side tags in the repeater, that did not work.

How can i stop this from happening?

Example: 
On Server: 
    http://www.someurl.com/registration?pcid=FREE15&pid=a1V80000000PQ6zEAG 

On client: 
    http://www.someurl.com?pcid=FREE15&pid=a1V80000000PQ6zEAG

Comment: This is by design. Per the HTML spec the ampersand "&" cannot exist by itself. http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_12

Comment: @Chris, the & is part of the URL

Comment: All ampersands in a URL must be encoded as `&amp;` when written in HTML, no exceptions

Comment: @Chris When we encode it to &amp; in the aspx page, it still renders as &amp

Comment: @aspnetdev, So are you actually getting double-encoding? Your raw html looks like `&amp;amp;`. Is whatever you're binding do already URL Encoded then? For instance, if you're binding to a database does your database actually have `&amp;` in the URL instead of just `&`?

Comment: @Chris, yes i get the string from the DB with & and i encode it.. so i can see the string is being sent to the asp.net repeater with &amp; but then in the HTML it is still shown as &amp;

Answer (score 0):

@aspnetdev, which row below shows what the url looks like in your database, 1 or 2?

```
---------------------------------------------------
| ID | URL                                        |
---------------------------------------------------
|  1 | http://www.example.com/?id=1&name=test     |
|  2 | http://www.example.com/?id=1&amp;name=test |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Is this a rough approximation of what your repeater looks like?

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repMain">
 <HeaderTemplate>
  <ul>
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <FooterTemplate>
  </ul>
 </FooterTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
   <li><a href="<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Url")%>"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Url")%></a></li>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

If your row look like #2 I ***highly*** recommend that you decode the URLs in your database as in row #1. You're going to be running into issues constantly if you use the #2 method.

Using the above repeater, row #1 will look like:

```
<li><a href="http://www.example.com/?id=1&name=test">http://www.example.com/?id=1&name=test</a></li>
```

This is actually invalid HTML because all literal ampersands must be escaped using `&amp;`

Here's how row #2 will appear:

```
<li><a href="http://www.example.com/?id=1&amp;name=test">http://www.example.com/?id=1&amp;name=test</a></li>
```

This is valid HTML and should not be corrected.

Can you elaborate on my samples or post some of your own?

Comment: This is how the client side repeater looks like - http://paste.pocoo.org/show/335173/
The OnClientClick will get the URL with the &